# Comparing Column Contents in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have a rather unique problem that I've never come across in Excel which I'll assume will carry over to Google Sheets:

I need to compare multiple cells in certain columns to a text value, and if that value is true, I need the values in the cells directly adjacent (left and right) of the cell that returns true to be placed into completely separate cells in different columns.

Example:
Cells in column C: C22 to C40 can contain anything but if any of them contain the word "foo" then the cell directly left of the cell that contains "foo" will have its contents copied to cell E56 or whatever it may be and the cell directly to the right will be placed into cell G56.

I have absolutely zero idea how to accomplish this, and for that matter my professor doesn't either. Maybe the good people of stackoverflow can be of assistance?

I should add that I feel this should be done with separate statements on each of the receiving cells unless that is the complete wrong thing to do.

I've tried something like this but I don't know how to get the values from the ORs that return a true value:

=IF((OR(C13="foo", C14="foo", C15="foo", C16="foo", C17="foo")????)"Empty")

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you post what you've tried.  Even if you aren't sure it will work, it's best to try something and ask why it's not working than to ask an open-ended question.  Maybe start with using something like `vlookup` to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are the values in those cells unique? What happens if there are 2 cells with the word "foo" in them?

Comment: I would, but it won't let me post anything useful with my reputation so low. Like, I've tried =IF(COUNTIF(OR(C22:C40 = "foo"),"bar","notbar")) (not completely syntax correct) but that doesn't give me the ability to segregate what is in the cells directly to the left and right and input them into the next cell I need them to be in.

Comment: Like something like this doesn't work. How to get the values from the OR's that return true? =IF((OR(C13="foo", C14="foo", C15="foo", C16="foo", C17="foo")????)"Empty")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IF(C14 = "foo", B14, IF(C15 = "foo", B15, IF(C16 = "foo", B16, IF(C17 = "foo", B17, "Empty"))))

Figured it out. Thanks anyway!